# Одно UIView, одно self.view, два addSubview()

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

Что будет если:

```
 let label = UILabel(someFrame)
 view.addSubview(label)
 view.addSubview(label)
```

Два объекта в памяти или...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` будет один.
Два объекта не повяитсья, откуда.
На самом деле при повторном добвляении `label` ссылка на `superview` (view) для `label` удалиться и запишеться новая на тот же `superview`.